# .redirect() from mounted middleware with relative destination fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to restrict a certain subtree only to authenticated users. The basic setup is as follows (fat removed):

```
app.use(express.bodyParser())
 .use(express.cookieParser('MY SECRET'))
 .use(express.cookieSession())
 .use('/admin', isAuthenticatedHandler)
 .use('/admin', adminPanelHandler);
```

Where the handler functions is:

```
isAuthenticatedHandler = function(req, res, next) {
   if (!req.session.username) {
     res.redirect('login');
   } else {
     next();
   }
};
```

The problem is that even though I provide the redirect destination as a relative path 'login', it doesn't lead to `<mount_point>/login` i.e. `/admin/login` but to `/login` which of course throws a 404.

From the expressjs API reference:

```
 This next redirect is relative to the mount point of the application. 
 For example if you have a blog application mounted at /blog, ideally 
 it has no knowledge of where it was mounted, so where a redirect of 
 /admin/post/new would simply give you `http://example.com/admin/post/new`, 
 the following mount-relative redirect would give you
 `http://example.com/blog/admin/post/new`:

      res.redirect('admin/post/new');
```

Am I misreading this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that while you are using your middleware off of `/admin`, your app itself is not mounted at `/admin`.  Your app is still off of the root, and your configuration simply says to only use your `isAuthenticatedHandler` middleware if the request comes in off the `/admin` path.

I whipped together [this gist](https://gist.github.com/juanpaco/8417295).  Notice how it uses 2 Express applications, one mounted inside the other (line 23 pulls this off).  That is an example of mounting the application at a different point rather than just putting a given middleware at a given point.  As presently written, that example will give you an endless redirect, since the `isAuthenticatedHandler` fires for everything off of `/` in the child application, which equates to `/admin` overall.  Using 2 separate applications might introduce other issues you're not looking to deal with, and I only include the example to show what Express means when it talks about mounting entire applications.

For your present question, you'll either need to follow what Yashua is saying and redirect to `/admin/login` or mount your admin interface as a separate Express application.

Comment: First of, I didn't know you could have a `mount point` for the app overall. Even so, your proposal postpones the inevitable which is middleware reusability: what happens when I decide to use the `isAuthenticatedHandler` middleware on another mount-point besides `/`? I'd face the same issue again. Also Yashua's solution is not applicable because the middleware is unaware of where it is mounted each time.

Comment: That's the very point I was making.  Express doesn't support what you're looking for right out of the box with that middleware as written.  You can have a middleware apply only to certain paths, but there's no concept of "mounting" it.

Now you could make a change to your middleware and do something like this: [https://gist.github.com/juanpaco/8420283](https://gist.github.com/juanpaco/8420283).  You'd have to "manually" scope your middleware, but notice that you can now reuse that middleware and easily configure it for different "mount" points.

Comment: Of course, now you'll need to parameterize what property you check on `req.session`, but that could easily be added as another parameter on the outer function.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? Why not just redirect to '/admin/login' ?  And the mount point they are talking about is the place where your Express app is located, not necessarily the current URL. So /blog might be setup on your server to be the root of your app while / might be a totally different app. At least that's the way I read this.

Comment: I'm interpreting `mount point` in the Expressjs way i.e. as a path prefix for middleware which allows writing middleware as if it were at the root level and use it on any path prefix without altering the code. 
I'm trying to achieve having a reusable middleware for checking authentication. That's why I don't want to redirect to `/admin/login`. Because that would beat the while purpose of the reusability that the mount-point offers.